# How to use Angular to post data to MVC action in SPA sample project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angular

I'm using the sample SPA project in visual studio 2017. I added a button in component, so it looks like:

```
<h1>Counter</h1>
<p>This is a simple example of an Angular component.</p>
<p>Current count: <strong>{{ currentCount }}</strong></p>
<button (click)="incrementCounter()">Increment</button>
<button (click)="setCounter()">Set Counter</button>
```

When click the Set Counter button, I want to post the value back to Action. Here is added in component.ts:

```
public setCounter() {

    this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'api/SampleData/SetCounter',
      { 'counter': this.currentCount },
      { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } }
    ).subscribe(result => {
        console.log(result);
        this.currentCount = result;
    }, error => console.error(error));
}
```

Here is the C# code in controller:

```
[HttpGet("[action]")]
public int GetCounter()
{
    return Counter;
}

[HttpPost("[action]")]
public int SetCounter(int counter)
{
    Counter = counter;  // here counter is always 0
    return Counter;
}
```

The post call actually goes to the SetCounter, but the value of counter is always 0, event I the currentCount > 0 directly. It looks like I did not call the post correctly. Anyone knows where is the issue?

I just start to learn angular using visual studio and will need to use it in a MVC5 project we take over.

Thanks

Comment: Try changing your endpoint declaration in the controller to be this: `public int SetCounter([FromBody]int counter)`

Comment: add FromBody, same issue. Counter is a static property in the controller. the issue is counter is always 0 (lower case counter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As R. Richards said use

public int SetCounter([FromBody] int counter) or you could also use FromURI

See https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/frombody-and-fromuri-in-webapi/

Also in your angular code you are passing a JSON object {'counter': 123}. But the parameter you're binding is an integer. So you either create a model  with counter as an attribute in the webapi and use that as the parameter or just pass the number. 
To be clear :

```
[HttpPost]
public void Post([FromBody] int value)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Value --> " + value.ToString() );
}
```

will require just an integer in the body of the http.post(url, 123, options) call.
If you want to pass {'counter':123} then you will have to modify your controller as such:

```
public class myObject{
 public int counter;
}    

[HttpPost]
public void Post([FromBody] myObject value)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Value --> " + value.counter.toString() );
}
```